# Data mean by intervals in IDL

Tags: python, split, average, mean, idl-programming-language

I did the following script to integrate (average) data by intervals in python:

```
# N = points to mean in the array
# data = original data
# data_mean = average data each N points

data_mean = np.array([np.mean(i) for i in np.array_split(data, len(data)/N)])
```

How could do that in IDL?
There are a "mean" function, but a "array_split-like"?

Answer (score 2):

The `array_split` functionality is usually done via `REFORM` to create a two (or higher) dimensional array from a 1-dimensional array using the same values. So for example:

```
n = 20
data = randomu(seed, 100)
data = reform(data, 100 / n, n)
print, mean(data, dimension=2)
```

Comment: I got the fllowing message after printing mean(data, dimension=2): % Keyword DIMENSION not allowed in call to: MEAN
% Execution halted at: $MAIN$

Comment: It work but REFORM is simlar to RESHAPE. When I was using RESHAPE, i didnt be able to reshape in a non-multiple of the number of elements

Comment: The `DIMENSION` keyword to `MEAN` was added in IDL 8.0. Pre-8.0, use `TOTAL` and divide by the number of elements. There has been a `dimension` second parameter in `TOTAL` for a long time.

Comment: `REFORM` does require the number of elements in each dimension to be a multiple of the total number of elements. What do you want to happen in that case? You could pad the array with `NaN`s or some other value.

Answer (score 0):

The IDL `mean` function is equivalent to the numpy `mean` function, and the IDL `reform` can be used similarly to the numpy `array_split`:

```
data_mean = mean(reform(data, n_elements(data) / N), dimension=2)
```

If you don't mind `data` ending up with different dimensions, you can greatly speed this up using the `/overwrite` keyword:

```
data_mean = mean(reform(data, n_elements(data) / N, /overwrite), dimension=2)
```

Finally, if you have a **version of IDL before IDL 8.0**, then you won't have the `dimension` keyword for the `mean` function. Use this (less elegant) pattern instead:

```
data_mean = total(reform(data, n_elements(data) / N), 2) / N
```

Note that this version with `total` also accepts the `/nan` keyword, so that it works even when some data are missing.